# How to send mail in Magento 2 from custom Module?

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, mail

I have created a custom module and in phtml file i have added html and by using ajax i will call the controller file.

But the issue is on using mail function it will show me an error on mail function parameter if i var dump the data it shows me bool(false).

I have configure Sendgrid to send mail and its test mail works so there is no problem with that all the test mail works fine so there will be an issue regarding the mail function with magento.

Is mail function didn't work in Magento 2 ?

Comment: No it doesn't solve my query @paj

Comment: wp_mail is a Wordpress function?

Comment: Sorry about that i have used php mail function @paj